wayland screen off script
hi trying to get wayland to turn off the display when there is no inputs(no mouse move, keyboard or touch) for 1 minute
i would like to run the command: dbus-send --session --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver --type=method_call \ /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.SetActive boolean:true
to turn off the display because its the most reliable i have found sudo ddcutil setvcp d6 5 also works to turn off the display but i would have to use sudo ddcutil setvcp d6 1 to turn it back on so i prefer to use dbus-send
yes i want to use wayland because it seems to be more optimized for touch as x11.
i can use this python script to check if idle now i just have to combine this all in a script, any and all help with be appriciated.
idle timer python script

I'd say you will very soon be fed up with the screen blanking that quick:
I have done this instead, first do
$ cd 
$ mkdir bin

then create a file in bin/ with this content:
$ cat bin/blankscreen
#!/bin/env bash
# sudo apt install libxcb-dpms0* ?
sleep 1 && xset dpms force off

... when it exists, do $ chmod 755 bin/blankscreen
Then go into

Settings
Keyboard
View and customize shortcuts
Custom Shortcuts
click the +
... and type in e.g.

"immediate screen blanking" for Name,
and /home/YOUR_USERNAME/bin/blankscreen for Command
and then Click Set Shortcut
and hit any key combination to use to blank the screen (i.e. use/run the script above).

Option: change the file to this instead:    
#!/bin/env bash
sleep 1 &&  \
dbus-send --session --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver \
          --type=method_call /org/gnome/ScreenSaver \
          org.gnome.ScreenSaver.SetActive boolean:true

... (same as Win-key+L) the difference is that one need to enter the password as it turns off, depending on settings:
See Settings > Privacy and Security > Screen Lock > ...
Note: \ and line breaks added (here) for readability.

In use on Ubuntu 24.04...

thanks, as far as i know xset dpms force off does not work
i get this: server does not have extension for dpms option
xset:  unknown option force

Check if sudo apt install libxcb-dpms0* changes that. A bare xset dpms might also affect it.

nope same errors i thought dpms just didnt work with wayland or is my thinking wrong, its so hard to find good information about wayland.

Sad... I have it working on my 24.04, so "it works for me" - while expecting things to be Wayland, as I have not actively changed to X.

Option added above: does this do the trick for you?

how would i make a script that checks a value (idleTime)(in ms) in idletime.py if its more than 1 minute it should run sleep 1 &&  \ dbus-send --session --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver \           --type=method_call /org/gnome/ScreenSaver \           org.gnome.ScreenSaver.SetActive boolean:true

Right, you do not wish to use a shortcut key. I do not (currently) know how to achieve what you ask for.

Note: Windows+L

After not finding any solution i learned some python and combined some scripts and wrote some of my own this is the script i am using to turn off the screen and back on if motion or touch. (its for a interactive touch display) my code is probably horrible but hey it kinda works. maybe ill throw it at chatgpt to see what that comes up with.
#!/usr/bin/env python
from gpiozero import MotionSensor                                                                                                                                                            
import subprocess
import time

time.sleep(10)

# GPIO-Pin für den Bewegungssensor
MOTION_SENSOR_PIN = 11

# Befehl zum Einschalten des Touchscreen-Monitors
TURN_ON_COMMAND = "dbus-send --session --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver --type=method_call --print-reply --reply-timeout=20000 /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.SetActive boolean:false"

# Befehl zum Ausschalten des Touchscreen-Monitors
TURN_OFF_COMMAND = "dbus-send --session --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver \
          --type=method_call /org/gnome/ScreenSaver \
          org.gnome.ScreenSaver.SetActive boolean:true"

# Initialisierung des Bewegungssensors
motion_sensor = MotionSensor(MOTION_SENSOR_PIN)

# Funktion zum Einschalten des Touchscreen-Monitors
def turn_on_screen():
    subprocess.run(TURN_ON_COMMAND, shell=True)

# Funktion zum Ausschalten des Touchscreen-Monitors
def turn_off_screen():
    subprocess.run(TURN_OFF_COMMAND, shell=True)
# Hauptfunktion
def main():
    try:
        while True:
            def get(cmd):
# Idle Time Script Wie Lange kein inputs
                    return subprocess.Popen(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)

            get_idleTime = "dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor /org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor.GetIdletime"

            idleTime = int((get(get_idleTime)).communicate()[0].rsplit(None,1)[-1])
            # Ueberprüfe auf Bewegung
            if motion_sensor.motion_detected:
                turn_on_screen()
                print("Bewegung erkannt! Bildschirm eingeschaltet.")
                # Warte eine Weile, bevor du erneut nach Bewegung suchst
                time.sleep(30)
            elif idleTime < 10000:

                print("Touch input! warten bis kein input.")
                print(idleTime)
                turn_on_screen()
                time.sleep(10)
            else:
                print("display Aus")
                turn_off_screen()
                time.sleep(0.5)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Programm beendet.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()`



